# npm live-server install: symlink error (even when running as root/admin)

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, ubuntu, npm

I'm working with an AngularJS tutorial book ([*Unraveling AngularJS 1.5 (With Over 130 Complete Samples* by István Novák)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00ULTPP00)) which requires **Node.js** to be installed. In the appendix in the back of the book, it lists command line codes to install various packages to work with Node.js, using NPM. The last component listed is **live-server**. I am running the following commands:

```
npm init -y
npm install angular@^1.5.0 --save
npm install angular-messages@^1.5.0 --save
npm install angular-route@1.5.0-beta.2 --save
npm install bootstrap --save
npm install jquery --save
npm install live-server --save-dev
```

Everything worked just fine except for live-server. When I try to install this component, I get the following error messages (this is pulled from the `npm-debug.log` file):

```
335 warn UnravelingAngular1.5@1.0.0 No repository field.
336 verbose stack Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, symlink '../mime/cli.js' -> '/media/usb/AngularJS Test/Samples/node_modules/.bin/mime'
336 verbose stack     at Error (native)
337 verbose cwd /media/usb/AngularJS Test/Samples
338 error Linux 4.4.0-31-generic
339 error argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "live-server" "--save-dev"
340 error node v4.4.7
341 error npm  v3.10.5
342 error path ../mime/cli.js
343 error code EPERM
344 error errno -1
345 error syscall symlink
346 error Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, symlink '../mime/cli.js' -> '/media/usb/AngularJS Test/Samples/node_modules/.bin/mime'
346 error     at Error (native)
346 error  { [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, symlink '../mime/cli.js' -> '/media/usb/AngularJS Test/Samples/node_modules/.bin/mime']
346 error   errno: -1,
346 error   code: 'EPERM',
346 error   syscall: 'symlink',
346 error   path: '../mime/cli.js',
346 error   dest: '/media/usb/AngularJS Test/Samples/node_modules/.bin/mime',
346 error   parent: 'UnravelingAngular1.5' }
347 error Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
348 verbose exit [ -1, true ]
```

As to the line at the end suggesting running as root/admin -- I've tried this using root (I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS), with the same unsuccessful result (same error codes and everything). Apparently it's a symlink issue, but I know nothing about those. All other components downloaded via NPM worked just fine.

**How would one resolve the symlink issue as suggested?**

Comment: The problem is probably a missing directory `node_modules/.bin`. Out of context, it's impossible to tell what should have created it, and whether there is a bug in this package.

Comment: @tripleee what other context do u need?

Comment: Here is the list of commands given in the book's appendix:
`npm init -y`
`npm install angular@^1.5.0 --save`
`npm install angular-messages@^1.5.0 --save`
`npm install angular-route@1.5.0-beta.2 --save`
`npm install bootstrap --save`
`npm install jquery --save`
`npm install live-server --save-dev`
Everything worked just fine except for live-server.

Comment: Also @tripleee I checked and `/node_modules/.bin` exists, but not the `mime` sub-folder. Would manually creating it fix the issue?

Comment: What is the filesystem that you're using? It looks like a USB drive, perhaps it's using a file system that doesn't support symlinks?

Comment: btw are you using chrome OS because that does not support symlinks

Comment: @robertklep I think that might be it! My USB drive appears to be using a FAT32 filesystem, which I guess isn't compatible with symlinks. I think I will need to format and switch to NTFS, can you confirm if this is correct?

Comment: @l--''''''---------'''''''''''' I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Xenial on a Dell Inspiron, but I also have a Chromebook so that is good to know!

Comment: Let me know as soon as you resolve this issue. Can't believe angular developers are clueless about this

Comment: @Matt I can't confirm because I've never used NTFS myself, but it's certainly a much more "complete" fs than FAT32 is.

Comment: @robertklep are you suggesting that he should reformat the usb drive and there wouldnt be an issue any longer?

Comment: @–... no, I'm merely suggesting that the filesystem in use may not support symlinks. OP suggested to reformat the drive to NTFS, but I can't confirm nor deny that that will solve the issue (due to lack of experience with NTFS).

Comment: I've decided to try EXT4 because that's what my OS uses, and it apparently supports symlinks.

Answer (score -2):

Please check: **347 error Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.** If not, you should try to check compatible node module version. You can remove and install lite-server by command **npm install lite-server -g**. lite-server can install separately.

Comment: What is the difference between **lite-server** and **live-server**? I'm trying to deviate as little as possible from the book's specifications.

Comment: sorry for my mistake: you can install lite-server or live-server as global.